# Return data in Laravel/Lumen Controller

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

So I know you can pass data to a view in `laravel` like so;

```
return view('pages.index', ['year' => $year, 'b' => $cookie]);
```

But what if I'm not returning a `view`?
Basically I have a the below setup;

```
route -> controller  // on API server
```

With the `request` coming from my `web server`

I know I can pass a `string` from my controller like so;

```
$response = "Valid";
return $response;
```

So I get `Valid` as a `response` in my Angular `request`

```
success (function(response, status, headers, config){
   if (response == "Valid") .....
})
```

Can I pass data and then access it there? In addition to "Valid" like is done here `return view('pages.index', ['year' => $year, 'b' => $cookie]);`

Answer (score 2):

If you return an array of scalar values, an object implementing **Jsonable** interface or array of such objects, Laravel will automatically serialize it and return **JSON** response.

Try the following:

```
 return ['year' => $year, 'b' => $cookie];
```